execute this curl post command through robotframework
I want to execute this curl command throgh robotframework
curl -X 'POST' \
  '
https://localhost:8443/ABCD/9/XYZ?operation=CREATE&reason=10'
\
  -H 'accept: application/json' \
  -H 'Content-Type: multipart/form-data' \
  -F 'file=@bulk_insert_sample.txt;type=text/plain'

I write like this:
File Valid
    ${headers}=    Create Dictionary    Authorization=Bearer ${ACCESS_TOKEN}    accept=application/json    Content-Type=multipart/form-data
    Create Session    bulk_upload    ${BASE_URL}    verify=False
    ${response}=    POST On Session    bulk_upload    ${ENDPOINT_BULK_UPLOAD}    headers=${headers}    files={"file": ("bulkinsert.txt", open("${FILE_PATH}", "rb"), "${CONTENT_TYPE}")}
    Should Be Equal As Numbers    ${response.status_code}    200

But I am getting this error
${response} =   RequestsLibrary . POST On Session   bulk_upload    ${ENDPOINT_BULK_UPLOAD}    headers=${headers}    files={"file": ("bulkinsert.txt", open("${FILE_PATH}", "rb"), "${CONTENT_TYPE}")}
Documentation:  
Sends a POST request on a previously created HTTP Session.

Start / End / Elapsed:  20240912 09:00:18.429 / 20240912 09:00:18.438 / 00:00:00.009
09:00:18.432    FAIL    ValueError: cannot encode objects that are not 2-tuples

